# jQuery Variable width slider

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I normally hate asking these kind of questions, but I am running out of time.

I prefer to write sliders and carrousels etc my own however my time is very limited.

Having tried numerous different carrousels, none seem to do what I want.

What I need is a carousel which is full-width and has a fixed height. The items shown should be variable and so are the widths of the items, but the width of the slider should always be filled with slider items, even if they are only shown partially and should also be circular.

I created a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BFS3q/ which mighy explain my question better, I used the caroufredsel plugin with this which almost does what I need but does not always show items partially.

Perhaps if someone knows how to do this with caroufredsel, here is what I used:

```
$("#slider").carouFredSel({
        width: "100%",
        align:"left",
        height: 150,
        direction :"left",
        items: {
            minimum: 1,
            start: 8,
            width: "variable",
            height: 150,
            visible: "variable"
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            easing: "linear"
        },
        auto: true,
        next: "#next",
        prev: "#prev"
    });
```

Comment: have you checked this one? http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/variable-visible-variable-size.php

Comment: Hi Tim, yes I have. The thing is that that example does not show slides partially when possible. The items are centered with white space arround them. That is exactly what I need to avoid, the slider always should be filled, even if an image gets cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php

I this what you are looking for?